# Link cell values and their formats across different tabs

Tags: google-sheets

Here's what I have in one Google Sheets:

12 tabs for Jan - Dec
1 tab for 2015

For B1 in `tab2015`, how do I link from Jan!B1 **WITH the formatting**, so if I change B1 in `tabJan`, B1 in `tab2015` will also change, even if formatting is changed too?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "linking" cells. Should `Jan!B1` contain a hyperlink to `2015!B1`? And should the formatting stay the same as it would be without the hyperlink?

Comment: Still not completely clear. Do you mean: if you change the formatting of `Jan!B1`, the formatting of `2015!B1` will autmatically change in the same way?

Comment: Yes, you got it. Is there a way to do that? I googled, many people said it's impossible?

Comment: Still in 2019 I couldn't find answer to this question. It looks like it is still impossible.

Comment: @likern It's not impossible. I just added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this by using an *on change installable trigger*. Here is a simple example for demoing purposes:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  
  if(
    source.getSheet().getName() === 'Sheet1' && 
    source.getA1Notation() === 'A1'
  ){    
    
    var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 2);
  
    /**
     * Set the formatting options of interest
     */
    Object.keys(formatting).forEach(function(key){
      switch (key) {
        case 'background':
          target.setBackground(source.getBackground());
          break;
        case 'fontColor':
          target.setFontColor(source.getFontColor());
          break;
        default:
          //
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Instead of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` we could use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)`;

The *on change installable trigger* could be created by code of by clicking on Edit > Current project's triggers

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

Not full answer, only part (constrained) solution, two semi-automatic workarounds:

1. Create a helper cell with a numeric or aplanumeric value, that teoretically represent formating setting. Create some (maybe complex) automatic "conditional formatting", the same for both source cell and linked cell. Then instead of changing cell format, write the value to the helper cell and let "conditional formatting" do the format change according to your helper cell value. Link also the helper cell value from source to destination and set the "conditional formatting" the same on both places. Result: if you set "format" by inserting value in the source helper cell, the destination helper cell will also change and both places will apply the duplicated "conditional formatting" rule -> both places will automatically change format. The hard part of warkaround is to create (maybe complex) "conditional formatting" rules that will satisfy your (maybe complex) formating idea
2. linking the cell value (classic), and manually copy only the format (Edit->Insert special..->Insert only the format) or create some complex Conditional formating on both places